# Export to Excel (DBNull Error)

Tags: c#, database, excel, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to export data onto separate spreadsheets based on Categories that are in a combobox. 
The combobox has a DataTable as the datasource. This DataTable has two columns: categoryid (ValueMember) and Category (DisplayMember).

The problem is, I get an error:

> "Object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types."

However, my DataTable is generated from the database, and both categoryid and Category CANNOT have NULLS.

Here is my code:

```
private void excelSpreadsheetToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string fname = "Inventory Report.xlsx";
        XLWorkbook xwb = new XLWorkbook();
        foreach (DataRowView dvrow in catcombobox.Items)
        {
                //gives integer to function (categoryid), and gives name to spreadsheet (Category)
                xwb.Worksheets.Add(exceldt(Convert.ToInt32(dvrow.Row["categoryid"])), dvrow.Row["Category"].ToString());
                xwb.SaveAs(fname);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private DataTable exceldt(int i)
{
    using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Item, Quantity, Date FROM inventory_table WHERE categoryid= " + i))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
            sqlda.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;

            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sqlda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I fix this?**

Attempt at solution:

```
                    if (!(dvrow.Row["categoryid"].Equals(DBNull.Value)))
                    {
                        xwb.Worksheets.Add(exceldt(Convert.ToInt32(dvrow.Row["categoryid"])), dvrow.Row["Category"].ToString());
                    }
```

Comment: Please, do consider using SQLParameters `using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Item, Quantity, Date FROM inventory_table WHERE categoryid= " + i))` this line is vulnerable.

Comment: why don't you change your query to also add an `And` to the where clause where you pull back data that is not null.. keep in mind `Null and Empty` are not the same thing @John

Comment: @MethodMan Noted. However, the categoryid column in my database CANNOT be `null`; its one of the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
if(dvrow.Row["categoryid"] != DBNull.Value){
    xwb.Worksheets.Add(exceldt(Convert.ToInt32(dvrow.Row["categoryid"])), dvrow.Row["Category"].ToString());
}
```

and move the `xwb.SaveAs(fname);` out of foreach, is more efficient.

and @Max say to use parameter in the query like this:

```
....
using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Item, Quantity, Date FROM inventory_table WHERE categoryid= @catid")){
...
  sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("catid", id));
....
}
```

Comment: I get the error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: @John I have update the code.. i think the problem come from  ```dvrow.Row["categoryid"]``` cast

Comment: I'm not trying to add an "id". I'm trying to pull data into a DataTable from a table in the database based on another tables' "categoryid".

Comment: I've posted the attempt at the solution. I end up getting the same error. I noticed in your code you say if the "row equals a DBNull value, then add the worksheet". Which is why I have the "NOT" in my `if` statement.

Comment: @John yes i have correct you need to add not in if ```!=``` not ```==```

Comment: @MethodMan i don't convert DBNull.Value to int32, i convert all the values not equal with DBNull

Comment: I didn't see the `!` sign at first.. sorry about that